# Text glow on page load in CSS/Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

How can I make text glow for a short time,  say a second, using Bootstrap and/or CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this script might be very useful:

http://patnakajima.com/jquery-glow/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.glow-me').addGlow({
    radius: 20,
    textColor: '#ff0',
    haloColor: '#ffa',
    duration: 200
  });
});
```

https://github.com/nakajima/jquery-glow

but using pure css , you can just use box shadow + glow effect ( not looking cool though )

http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=114

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px #ffffff; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ffffff; 
box-shadow:0 0 15px #ffffff;
```